Configure Dockerfile within VS 2022 to use identical certificate (pfx) for two projects
I have a visual studio 2022 solution (version 17.10.2) containing two projects; one ASP.NET Core Web project (Razor pages) and one ASP.NET WebAPI project.
Now I want to use the same dev certificate for both of them and try to add those in the Dockerfile as follows:
`#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 443
COPY MYSOL.WebAPI/Certs/aspnetapp.pfx /https/aspnetapp.pfx
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MYSOL.WebAPI/MYSOL.WebAPI.csproj", "MYSOL.WebAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./MYSOL.WebAPI/MYSOL.WebAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MYSOL.WebAPI"
RUN dotnet build "./MYSOL.WebAPI.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./MYSOL.WebAPI.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mypassword
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MYSOL.WebAPI.dll"]`
But during build / debug I receive an error:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
The certificate is already in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities on the machine.
any help appreciated, thanks.
Adding certificate to trusted root store.
